# Views exposed filters - how to show "You searched for [exposed filters]" above results?

Tags: views

I'd like to summarize the current filters used on the data in the results.

What's the easiest way to do this?

```
[ ] Cats
[x] Dogs

[Search]


You searched for Dogs

===============================
Lassie        Movie star
Bones         Runner
Hobbes        Show-dog
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Exposed Filter Data](http://drupal.org/project/exposed_filter_data) module. With it you can print the filters used in the view header.

Comment: Cool, thanks!

Sadly, it's not compatible with the Better Exposed Filters module.

Gladly, I have a starting point if it's that important.  

Thanks!

http://drupal.org/node/1960340